# C# Case Statement And Linking To Other Classes, advice needed

Tags: c#

have a menu and submenu system, this submenu contains information about locating a driver's location, I want to be able to do a search within the if statement to find out where said Driver is located. I've attached a link to a screenshot if that helps.

http://imageshack.us/f/14/helpub.png/

I want to be able to press the number 1 (or any other number) and for the application to say the following instead of defaulting back to the depot menu:

Please enter name of driver (in this case Steven)
Then for the application to say:

"Steven is located at Depot A"

Any ideas, tips or suggestions greatly appreciated.
I don't want the coding done for me as this is cheating, I just want a pointing in the right direction

Rafa

Apologies, my first post. Okay what I want to happen is that when I press one in the screen the app will ask me to enter driver's name, driver's name is Kenny.  Then I want the app to display "Kenny is located at Depot Liverpool"  But I'm not sure how to do this.

Code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Sys
    {
        private bool isLoggedIn = false;
        private List<Depot> myDepots;

        public Sys()
        {
            myDepots = new List<Depot>();

            // Hard Code Data
            myDepots.Add(new Depot("Liverpool"));
            myDepots.Add(new Depot("Saint Helens"));

            // Hard Code Data
            myDepots[0].AddDriver(new Driver("Kenny", "07"));
            myDepots[0].AddDriver(new Driver("Steven", "08"));

            myDepots[1].AddDriver(new Driver("Jamie", "23"));
            myDepots[1].AddDriver(new Driver("Pepe", "25"));
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Pick Depot");

                for (int index = 0; index < myDepots.Count; index++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine((index + 1).ToString() + " : " + myDepots[index].GetDepotName());
                }

                int userChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                string userName = "", passWord = "";

                if ((userChoice > 0) && (userChoice < 3))
                {
                    Console.Write("Specify UserName : ");
                    userName = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.Write("Specify PassWord : ");
                    passWord = Console.ReadLine();

                    bool diditWork = myDepots[userChoice - 1].CheckPassword(userName, passWord);

                    if (diditWork)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("We are Logged On!");
                        Console.WriteLine(myDepots[userChoice - 1].GetMenu());
                        string menuInput;
                        int menuInt;

                        Console.Write("Please select a menu option: \n1 - Locate a Vehicle \n2 - Locate a Driver \n3 - Set up a Work Schedule \n4 - Exit Menu \n");
                        menuInput = Console.ReadLine();
                        menuInt = Int32.Parse(menuInput);

                        if (menuInt < 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Your menu selection is invalid, please try again", menuInt);
                            break;
                        }

                        if (menuInt == 1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Please enter model name of vehicle", menuInt);

                        }

                        if (menuInt == 2)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Please enter driver's surname", menuInt);
                            This is where I need the option to search a driver by name and then have their location reported back to the user of the app.  Basically I need the app to say Kenny is located at Depot A
                        }

                        if (menuInt == 3)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Please assign driver and vehcile to a new work schedule", menuInt);

                        }

                        if (menuInt > 4)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Your menu selection is invalid, please try again", menuInt);

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("We are Logged Off!");
                    }
                }

                isLoggedIn= false;

            } while (true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use a case statement with what you have and put whatever code you want in there, though most of us would get upset if it was more than five statements...

Looking at your probable intent though.

I think you want a "Task" class.

e.g.

```
switch(menuInt)
{
case 1 : Console.WriteLine(GetModelName); break;
case 2 : break; //etc
}
```

If you want to get a  bit more clever, define an interface that defines all the things that a menu option must do to intercat with your menu code. Write a class to do what you want, that implements the interface, then use a factory.

```
Console.Writeline(MenuItemFactory.CreateItem(menuInt).Response);
```

Maybe, hard to tell this early on. In fact may be it's a bit too early to start refactoring and you should just beaver away with at least a couple of the options before setting anything in stone.